# Plot 3D array using matplotlib or other python packages

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a 3 dimensional array using matplotlib, similar to pcolormesh for 2 dimensions. I have 3 position axes (x, y and z) and then a 3 dimensional grid for values at each x,y,z position. How can I do the same as you would with pcolormesh (x position, y position and then a 2 dimensional grid of values) but with 3 dimensions?

I've seen 3D scatter or surface plots but they don't seem to do what I want them to. I essentially want to create a volume plot, instead of a surface plot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [3D voxels](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.voxels.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.voxels) for that. The simplest thing to do would be probably normalizing your values to the range from 0 to 1, [generating colors with some color map](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/individual_colors_from_cmap.html#sphx-glr-gallery-color-individual-colors-from-cmap-py), and using these colors as "facecolors" to paint 3D voxels:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm

# generate 3D data array
values = np.random.rand(3, 3, 3)

x_num = values.shape[0]
y_num = values.shape[1]
z_num = values.shape[2]
                    
# all voxels are going to be filled
filled = np.ones((x_num, y_num, z_num), dtype=bool)

# make colors
cmap=cm.flag
facecolors = cmap(values)

# plot voxels
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
ax.voxels(filled=filled, facecolors=facecolors)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]

As you see, this kind of "3D color mesh" looks all right only for small data. When the data gets bigger, you could try to make gaps between 3D voxels, like in this example with [the NumPy logo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/voxels_numpy_logo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-voxels-numpy-logo-py), to be able to see the depths of data. Also, you could make the 3D voxels slightly transparent:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm

# the function is copied from this example: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/voxels_numpy_logo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-voxels-numpy-logo-py
def explode(data):
    size = np.array(data.shape)*2
    data_e = np.zeros(size - 1, dtype=data.dtype)
    data_e[::2, ::2, ::2] = data
    return data_e

# generate 3D data array
values = np.random.rand(4, 4, 4)

x_num = values.shape[0]
y_num = values.shape[1]
z_num = values.shape[2]
                    
# all voxels are going to be filled
filled = np.ones((x_num, y_num, z_num), dtype=bool)

# upscale the voxel image, leaving gaps
filled_2 = explode(filled)

# make colors
values_2 = explode(values)
cmap=cm.flag
facecolors_2 = cmap(values_2)

# plot voxels
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
ax.voxels(filled=filled_2, facecolors=facecolors_2, alpha=0.8)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]